# How to set a new column with identity?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table, in which I want to add a new column with identity. 
How to do that?

Also I want to set this newly created column as primary key and move it to the 1st column place renaming as `ID`.

How to do that?

Comment: *"move it to the 1st column"* is not possible unless you drop and recreate the table. But why would you need it in first place ?

Comment: To add a new column with identity property and primary key `Alter table tablename add ID Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key`

Comment: First of all the order of columns in a table make no difference at all. Second, a name of ID is a poor naming convention. It should ObjectID to avoid ambiguity. And one of my biggest pet peeves is a column names changing across tables. In other words you don't want an ID column in every table and its corresponding foreign key column to be ObjectID.

Comment: But I can't make a column primary which is not created using "Not Null" in the condition, right?

Comment: But I can't make a column primary which is not created using "Not Null" in the condition, right?

In that Case what to do? Update that column with distinct values and then make it primary, is it? 
But if I go in this way won't it be a tedious task?Like what if in a table hundreds of records have already been present .